# UIStackView, Autolayout, Table Cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm creating a `UIStackView` with an image and a label in a custom `UIControl` that will be in a custom `UITableViewCell`, except that my `UIStackView` has a height & width of 0 and XCode is complaining about breaking constraints. Only if I explicitly set a height and width does it show properly, which I don't want because the label text varies from cell to cell. (This is all happening programmatically.)

**The Setup**
In my `UITableViewCell`, I've got the following:

```swift
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
  super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  contentView.addSubview(control)

  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    control.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
    control.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
    control.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
    control.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
  ])
}

// empty coder init as well

private let control: MyControl = {
  let control: MyControl = MyControl()
  control.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  return control
}()
```

In `MyControl`, I just have the `UIStackView`, a `UIImageView`, and a `UILabel`. To not bore you with code...only the `UIStackView` (horizontal axis) is using constraints, pinning it to the four sides. The `UIImageView` (initiated with an image) is one arranged subview, the `UILabel` is the other (initiated with default text).

If you want to see the code:

```swift
class MyControl: UIControl {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(icon)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(contentLabel)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
      stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
      stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
      stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
    ])
  }

// empty coder init as well

  private let contentLabel: UILabel = {
    let label: UILabel = UILabel()
    label.text = "Initial text"
    return label
  }()

  private let icon: UIImageView = {
    let iv: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "placeholder_image")!)
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return iv
  }()

  private let stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView: UIStackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return control
  }()
}
```

**What I'm Expecting**
I'm *expecting* the `UIControl` to be the height of the image (because it's taller than the label text), and the width of the image + the label text. (And then display full table cell width because of that constraint pinning). And because these are set on initialization of these components, I'd expect them to have an intrinsic height and width to pass to the `UIStackView`.

**What I'm Getting**
A height and width of zero, and XCode complaints of broken constraints. If I remove all constraints, I get no complaints but nothing appears (as if the height & width are zero but XCode doesn't care because I didn't set any constraints).

**What I've Tried**
Literally every combination of layout constraints, including none on everything and as many as I can on everything. What I'd *like* is for the image + label text to set the height and width of the `UIStackView` which would then set the height and width of the `UIControl`, which would then set the height in the `UITableViewCell` (I know I have width 100% - that will change later).

**Other Considerations**
There's nothing else special about my `UITableViewCell` that would cause any issue here except that in my actual code, I have a multi-line label above `MyControl` which should (and does) cause my `UITableViewCell` to expand in height.

Comment: Yes, that's what I expect. Same with the label with text. I'm expecting my 24x29 image to set the height of the stack view to 29, and for the width to be 24 + the width of the label. If I just pin the top and left of the stack view, I can see the image and label, but that doesn't affect my control dimensions. Do you see where I'm going or thinking wrong?

Comment: Then that's where I'm confused. The docs say "without additional constraints, the system calculates the size of the stack view based on its contents". So my stack view *is* expanding based on its contents, but that's not expanding the superview which is why I can't see it? If so, is there a way to achieve my desired fluid sizing without setting a specific height/width? Appreciate your help BTW!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your question is that so much of the code you've shown is bogus that it's hard to guess what you might actually be doing. You claim that in your table view cell (I presume it's a table view cell subclass) you are saying

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
```

But that would never compile, as `init(frame:)` is not the designated initializer for a UITableViewCell. You have code like this:

```
private let contentLabel: UILabel = {
    let label: UILabel = UILabel()
    label.text = "Initial text"
    return label
}
```

But that would never compile, as a function is not a label.

If we make allowances for all of that and fix your code, it's difficult to see what you would be doing wrong. I corrected your code so that it would compile, and I got this in my table view:

[image]

That might not be exactly what you were after, but the image view is certainly sizing the cells to its own height.

What you are doing is not at all how one makes and configures a table view cell (you should be doing the work in `cellForRowAt`, not hard coding the cell's image view and label contents in the cell's initializer), but given what you've shown, the image view does size the stack view which does size the cell (contrary to my own initial expectations).

Another issue is that you can't put an image view and a label into an autolayout situation without resolving the ambiguity as to which should predominate. I added this line to do that:

```
    iv.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow+1, for: .horizontal)
```

Comment: I think you sent me down the right path. I made some fixes to the bogus code - I was typing quickly in SO to get the concept out there - sorry for the typos. I had to recalibrate my thinking - that's why I needed another set of eyes. Appreciate your help.